# Basics of Command Line Arguments, Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-line, cmd

I am using Python2.7.5 in Windows 7. I'm new to command line arguments. I am trying to do this exercise:

Write a program that reads in a string on the command line and returns a table of the letters which occur in the string with the number of times each letter occurs. For example:

```
$ python letter_counts.py "ThiS is String with Upper and lower case Letters."
a  2
c  1
d  1
# etc.
```

I know how to add command line arguments to a file name and output them in a list in cmd (windows command prompt). 
However, I would like to learn how to work with command line arguments in python script- because I need to add/access the additional command line arguments and create a loop in order to count their letters.

Outside of cmd, I currently only have letter_counts.py as the filename- that's only one command line argument.

In python not cmd : how do I add and access command line arguments?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) list from the [sys](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#module-sys) module. It lets you access arguments passed in the command line.

For example, if your command line input was `python myfile.py a b c`, `sys.argv[0]` is myfile.py, `sys.argv[1]` is a, `sys.argv[2]` is b, and `sys.argv[3]` is c.

A running example (`testcode.py`):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    print sys.argv
```

Then, running (in the command line):

```
D:\some_path>python testcode.py a b c
['testcode.py', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to follow your advice. If simply entered in the python shell, sys.argv returns an empty list. If I write it in a .py file and the press "run module", it returns a list with 1 argument- the filename of the .py file. I have successfully added command line arguments to the very same file in cmd (returning a list) But sys.argv only responds to the name of the .py file- and continues to return a list of length one.

Comment: @user2547317 `sys.argv` will only have more than one element if you use command line to run the program, such as `python myfile.py a b c`.

Comment: I am entering python myfile.py a b c in cmd- should I be entering it elsewhere?

Comment: @user2547317 No, that is correct. I'm not exactly sure what you meant in your first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print sys.argv
counts={}
for st in sys.argv[1:]:
    for c in st:
        counts.setdefault(c.lower(),0)
        counts[c.lower()]+=1

for k,v in sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True):
   print "'{}' {}".format(k,v)
```

When invoked with `python letter_counts.py "ThiS is String with Upper and lower case Letters."` prints:

```
['./letter_counts.py', 'ThiS is String with Upper and lower case Letters.']
' ' 8
'e' 5
's' 5
't' 5
'i' 4
'r' 4
'a' 2
'h' 2
'l' 2
'n' 2
'p' 2
'w' 2
'c' 1
'd' 1
'g' 1
'o' 1
'u' 1
'.' 1
```

If you instead do not use quotes, like this: `python letter_counts.py ThiS is String with Upper and lower case Letters.` it prints:

```
['./letter_counts.py', 'ThiS', 'is', 'String', 'with', 'Upper', 'and', 'lower', 'case', 'Letters.']
'e' 5
's' 5
't' 5
'i' 4
'r' 4
'a' 2
'h' 2
'l' 2
'n' 2
'p' 2
'w' 2
'c' 1
'd' 1
'g' 1
'o' 1
'u' 1
'.' 1
```

Note the difference in the list `sys.argv` at the top of the output. The result is that whitespace between words is lost and the letter counts are the same.

Comment: Hi @drewk Thank you for your response. I've gotten this to work by having the code in the letter_counts.py file. Then I open cmd and invoke python letter_counts.py "ThiS is String with Upper and lower case Letters." Once I do that, in the cmd window, I see the output. Is that the right process? I can only executed command line arguments in the cmd window?

Comment: Yes, only the cmd window but you could invoke from another process and capture this output. What do you mean of 'Python' vs 'cmd'?

Comment: Got it..I meant Python shell vs command line prompt (cmd) window in Windows 7

Comment: I do not understand your question I am afraid.